# How can I force users to send mail using submission port (587) with Exim?

Tags: smtp, exim, smtp-auth

I would like to force users of a system to send email only using a submission port (such as 587) and then disable authentication on port 25 so I don't have users trying to authenticate using plain text.

What configuration changes would I need to make to disable authentication on 25 so users have to use a submission port to relay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Exim manual (section 38.1). Hope this helps:

> You can insist that any client that
>   uses the AUTH command for
>   authentication must start a TLS
>   session first, by setting
>   auth_over_tls_hosts. For example,
>
> auth_over_tls_hosts = *
>
> means that all authentication must
>   take place over secure sessions. This
>   setting does not force the matching
>   hosts to use AUTH, but if they do,
>   they must issue STARTTLS first. The
>   availability of the AUTH command is
>   advertised to such hosts only after a
>   TLS session has been started.